# How to use flock and file descriptors to lock a file and write to the locked file?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bash script that makes a cURL request and writes the output to a file called `resp.txt`.  I need to create an exclusive lock so that I can write to that file and not worry about multiple users running the script and editing the text file at the same time.

Here is the code that I expect to lock the file, perform the request, and write to the text file:

```
(
flock -e 200
curl 'someurl' -H 'someHeader' > resp.txt
) 200>/home/user/ITS/resp.txt
```

Is this the correct way to go about this?  My actual script is a bit longer than this, but it seems to break when I add the `flock` syntax to the bash script.

If someone could explain how these file descriptors work and let me know if I am locking the file correctly that would be awesome!

Comment: See `EXAMPLES` in the `flock(1)` manual page. These work well.
They are: `(; flock -n 9 || exit 1; # ... commands executed under lock ...; ) 9>/var/lock/mylockfile` and `[ ${FLOCKER} != $0 ] && exec env FLOCKER="$0 flock -en $0 $0 $@ ||`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not correct because when you do `( flock -e 200; ... ) 200> file`, you are truncating the file `file` *before* you get the exclusive lock. I think that you should do:

```
touch resp.txt
(
  flock -e 200
  curl 'someurl' -H 'someHeader' > resp.txt
) 200< resp.txt
```

to place the lock on the file opened as read only.

**Note.** Some shells do not support file descriptors larger than 9. Moreover the hardcoded file descriptor may already be used. With advanced shells (bash, ksh93, zsh), the following can be done:

```
touch resp.txt
(
  unset foo
  exec {foo}< resp.txt
  flock -e $foo
  curl 'someurl' -H 'someHeader' > resp.txt
)
```

Comment: I do need the curl command would write to the file though.  Am i misunderstanding how `flock` works?  I'm new to the file descriptors :/

Comment: @DuckPuncher The lock mechanism is separate from the read/write operations you can do on the file. So, `curl` can still write to the file. Note that this may be unsafe (or may not even work) with NFS, but do not use a shell script for file locking over NFS. With `bash`, you can also open the file for both reading and writing: `200<> resp.txt` but this shouldn't change anything.